# Laptop stops and starts charging randomly

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, battery, adapter

I have an ASUS laptop and it randomly starts and stops charging without moving the cables. The battery is brand new and seems to be working fine. The DC Adapter is professionally tested and seems to be OK. Could it be the DC Jack?

It often works for hours just fine, but sometimes stops charging for a few seconds and then continues (my screen brightness will then flash shortly so it's easy to notice). One time it would just not charge, but when I went to the computer shop it was working again.. Ever since it worked almost perfectly.

I need my laptop to be reliable for my work. I cannot go to work hoping and praying that my laptop would not be failing today.

If I move around the cables or the plug (yes, the plug can move a bit inside the jack, I think it is not supposed to be like this), it doesn't switch the charging on or off.

The light on the DC adapter is constantly blue, but when my laptop will not charge, the orange led light on my laptop, which indicates charging, will slowly blink instead of lighting up constantly, which should be the case.

Could it be a heating problem perhaps? I'm pretty sure that when my laptop has been turned off and not plugged in for about an hour, it will work.

I have an Asus A55VD-SX030V. I would prefer to try and fix the problem myself instead of paying the high price which the local repair shop is asking for it. But I need to know which part is to be replaced or checked. They adviced me to buy a new laptop, but I hope that I can repair this one since I don't have any other issues with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your location prone to power brown-outs? Does it do this if connected to a different wall socket?

Comment: @Burgi Thank you for helping me. I did have this problem also in other locations.

Comment: @Z0q If battery is new and cable is tested, the next likely thing is the port on the laptop. If it is spacious (wiggles) could be a sign of failure.
The easiest way to test this is by using another charger.

Comment: The port could be at fault, although some movement isn't necessarily a problem as it's [on a harness](http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-DC-POWER-JACK-SOCKET-HARNESS-CABLE-FOR-ASUS-A55VD-TH71-LAPTOP-/281874164390?hash=item41a1026aa6:g:mLgAAOSwEK9UIiW3) rather than soldered to a board. As such, these types can be more prone to movement, usually only up and down though. The fact that the lights on the laptop change when it stops charging makes me thing it's something to do with the power circuitry, or possibly a fault with the power adapter which may have a certain 'intelligence' to detect it's genuine.

Comment: @Jonno: I wonder if I should replace the DC Jack or the adapter. It looks like the DC Jack should be pretty easy to fix if it is not soldered.

The battery is an unofficial one by the way, but it works fine. I think it would be strange if it would not work only sometimes. If it is intelligent to know that it is unofficial, it would not charge at all, right? P.S.: If it is not charging, it does also not boot the laptop without battery. So I think it does not have anything to do with the battery!

Comment: Today it has been working fine almost the entire day. Just for a few seconds it stopped working.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, in my case with an Asus N56. It seems to be getting worse. Have you found what the issue might have been? I still use the original adapter and battery, and the battery isn't that new any more.

Comment: I have the same issue. My laptop supports charging both by DC jack and USB-C. When USB-C is used, everything is fine, with no charging interruptions, but when it's connected to the DC jack it stops charging randomly for a few seconds, without moving the cable or the computer itself. Tried wriggling the DC cable in order to reproduce the issue but without luck - it happens completely random and it cannot be reproduced by wriggling the cable or moving the jack.

Comment: @stz184 I think I eventually tried replacing the power adapter (cable) and it ended up solving the issue in my situation